# I have a friend in London, UK and he is a Romanian. Can he be my Sponsor on my trip to london?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I met my ****Romanian**** friend through a friend here in the Philippines during his vacations together with his friend for two weeks. He is a Romanian living and working in London for 5 years already.

In just a short period of time, I and he including his two other friends(Romanian and Filipino living in New York, USA) became very close and really enjoyed each other's company.

So when they left he( Romanian friend living in the UK) mentioned that if I wanted to visit London in the future for a short vacation trip he said that he can sponsor me by giving me accommodation, providing my day to day expenses, like leisure and etc.

My question is, is he allowed to be my sponsor? I'm planning to visit London for a week trip in August or September 2019.

Answer (score 4):

While we usually strive to answer from gov.uk as it's the source of truth, I will use Citizens Advice here. They are a charity and as such their advice is much less suspect than a for profit entity. Without further ado, [Getting a visa for family and friends to visit the UK](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/visas-family-and-friends/getting-a-visa-for-family-and-friends-to-visit-the-uk/):

> If you’re paying for their visit (eg for their flights and accommodation) ... include ... proof that you’re in the UK legally, eg a copy of your passport or visa

This is clearly stating your friend should be able to apply and pay for you.

Comment: Since Romania is part of the EEA countries he is allowed to work and live in the UK legally without getting a visa, he can prove that he can accommodate me by giving his bank statements, his passport(Romanian one), proof of his tenancy for the house and his working status. I just wanted to make that he can be my sponsor before I apply for a UK Tourist Visa (?)

Comment: Yes he can that's what this says, quite clearly. A copy of his passport will prove he is an EEA citizen.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you don't need to be a UK citizen to sponsor a Standard Visit Visa visa for the UK - a sponsorship is simply evidence that the visitor won't revert to public funds in the UK. The sponsor is not providing a character certificate of any kind, only an assurance that they will support the financial needs and/or provide an accommodation to their guest. Certainly, the sponsor would need to provide evidence that they can sponsor you in the form of bank statements, documents like rental agreements if providing accommodation and proof of their own citizenship/legal residence in the UK.

I am an Indian national and have sponsored a Standard Visitor Visa of another Indian in the past, which was successful.

Comment: What other things do I need to submit aside from my (COE, bank certificate and statements that I have an income for the last 6 months and also a proof that I will be coming back to the PH) I wanted to make sure cause I don't want my first to try to fail.

Comment: Read the link I provided, it answers this